# Why does cout << not print inputs from left to right?

Tags: c++, cout, order-of-execution, sequence-points

the following code:

```
myQueue.enqueue('a');
myQueue.enqueue('b');
cout << myQueue.dequeue() << myQueue.dequeue();
```

prints "ba" to the console

while:

```
myQueue.enqueue('a');
myQueue.enqueue('b');
cout << myQueue.dequeue();
cout << myQueue.dequeue();
```

prints "ab" why is this?

It seems as though cout is calling the outermost (closest to the ;) function first and working its way in, is that the way it behaves?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There's no sequence point with the `<<` operator so the compiler is free to evaluate either `dequeue` function first. What is guaranteed is that the result of the second `dequeue` call (in the order in which it appears in the expression and not necessarily the order in which it is evaluated) is `<<`'ed to the result of `<<`'ing the first (if you get what I'm saying).

So the compiler is free to translate your code into some thing like any of these (pseudo intermediate c++). This isn't intended to be an exhaustive list.

```
auto tmp2 = myQueue.dequeue();
auto tmp1 = myQueue.dequeue();
std::ostream& tmp3 = cout << tmp1;
tmp3 << tmp2;
```

or

```
auto tmp1 = myQueue.dequeue();
auto tmp2 = myQueue.dequeue();
std::ostream& tmp3 = cout << tmp1;
tmp3 << tmp2;
```

or

```
auto tmp1 = myQueue.dequeue();
std::ostream& tmp3 = cout << tmp1;
auto tmp2 = myQueue.dequeue();
tmp3 << tmp2;
```

Here's what the temporaries correspond to in the original expression.

```
cout << myQueue.dequeue() << myQueue.dequeue();
|       |               |    |               |
|       |____ tmp1 _____|    |_____ tmp2 ____|
|                       |
|________ tmp3 _________|
```

Comment: so, in the top example, would
std::ostream& tmp3 = cout << tmp1;
tmp3 << tmp2;
be like saying "cout << tmp1 << tmp2;"? Or something I'm missing?

Comment: @segfault: Yes, because that is the way `<<` associates in C++ grammar. `a << b << c` always groups as `(a << b) << c`.

Comment: but by that logic, wouldnt saying cout << a << b be saying (cout << a) << b and do anything necessary to cout a first (i.e. call myQueue.dequeue())?

Comment: The associativity doesn't say anything about the order in which the subexpressions are evaluated. `cout << a << b` always means `(cout << a) << b` but the compiler is free to evaluate `b` first, then `a`, then the first `<<` operation and the the second. This is exactly the point that I made in my answer.

Comment: Sorry to comment on an old post, but C++11 1.9/15 (C++03 1.9/17) seems to imply that the sequencing constraints on overloaded operators are different. If my understanding is correct, the above is either `cout.operator<<(a).operator<<(b)`, or `operator<<(operator<<(cout,a),b)` depending on whether the operator is a member or free function. Both would imply a defined evaluation order for subexpressions `a` and `b`. Is that correct?

Comment: @jogojapan: This particular fact hasn't changed in C++11 although the concept of _sequence point_ has been replaced. In neither of the expressions that you've shown is there a constraint between the evaluation of `a` and `b`. Either may be evaluated before the other. There are other constraints, such as `b` must be evaluated before either `operator<<` as it is a direct or indirect argument to both of them and `a` must be evaluated before the `operator<<` to which it is a direct argument but the expressions `cout`, `a`, and `b` may be evaluated in any order w.r.t. each other.

Answer (score 9):

The call from your example:

```
cout << myQueue.dequeue() << myQueue.dequeue();
```

translates to the following expression with two calls of `operator<<` function:

```
operator<<( operator<<( cout, myQueue.dequeue() ), myQueue.dequeue() );
-------------------- 1
---------2
```

The order of evaluation of `cout`, `myQueue.dequeue()` is unspecified. However, the order of `operator<<` function calls is well specified, as marked with `1` and `2`

Answer (score 8):

Since C++17 the behaviour of this code has changed;  the left operand of `<<` is sequenced before the right operand of `<<`, even when it is an overloaded operator. The output must now be `ab`.

For further reading see: [What are the evaluation order guarantees introduced by C++17?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38501587/).