# GCC bug? Chaining methods, broken sequence point

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-bug

I've been debugging a program for some time, and eventually found the error was due to a reference not being updated as I thought it would be.

Here's a example that shows the problem I encountered:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Test {
    Test& set(int& i){ i = 10; return *this; }
    Test& print(const int& i){ cout << i << endl; return *this; }
};

int main(void){
    int i = 0;
    Test t;

    t.set(i).print(i + 5);

    return 0;
}
```

I had expected that the print() method here would output 15, but instead it outputs 5.

EDIT: 10 days later I just realised that with clang it outputs 15! Is this a bug in GCC?

Comment: Why write such code that both looks ugly and will always likely to be subject to errors? Why the requirement to chain methods?

Comment: @EdHeal I have a class with many methods that each do very little, and need to call a lot of them in a row. I chose to allow chaining like this to save quite a bit of typing. Now that I have found this behaviour I'll consider removing the chaining.

Comment: Too much haste less speed.

Comment: You pass `0 + 5` to `print()` and than print it directly. Debug your code next time.

Comment: @StoryTeller Then why do g++ and clang++ differ in their outputs?

Comment: @Xeno, Because the temporary which holds the parameter for print doesn't have to be defined after set returns. It's undefined behavior.

Comment: @StoryTeller: there's no temporary. Read the code carefully next time.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath, what's `i + 5`!?

Comment: @StoryTeller are you sure that the temporary doesn't have to be defined after set returns? the dot operator is a sequence point, I thought this meant otherwise.

Comment: @Xano, A sequence point means that everything before it has a well defined value. However, there's enough wriggle room in the standard for the compiler to optimize creating the temporary for the chained call in advance. If I had my standard handy, I'd start quoting.

Comment: @Xeno The whole term "sequence point" was always rather confusing. In the current standard it's replaced with "this is sequenced before (or after) that".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let me try interpreting the C++11 standard on this. In §1.9/15 it says:

> Except where noted, evaluations of operands of individual operators and of subexpressions of individual expressions are unsequenced. [...] If a side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to either another side effect on the same scalar object or a value computation using the value of the same scalar object, the behavior is undefined.

Certainly `int` is an scalar type, and `t.set(i).print(i + 5);` contains a side effect on `i` in `set()` and the value computation `i + 5`, so if not noted otherwise, the behavior is indeed undefined. Reading §5.2.5 ("Class member access"), I could not find any notes about sequences regarding the `.` operator. [But see edit below!]

Note, however that it is of course guaranteed that `set()` is executed before `print()` because the latter receives the return value of the former as an (implicit `this`) argument.
The culprit here is that the value computation for `print`'s arguments is <del>unsequenced</del> indeterminately sequenced relative to the call of `set`.

EDIT: After reading the answer in your (@Xeno's) comment, I reread the paragraph in the standard, and in fact it later says:

> Every evaluation in the calling function (including other function calls) that is not otherwise specifically sequenced before or after the execution of the body of the called function is indeterminately sequenced with respect to the execution of the called function.

Because *indeterminately sequenced* is not *unsequenced* ("execution of unsequenced evaluations can overlap", §1.9/13), this is indeed not undefined behavior, but "just" unspecified behavior, meaning that both 15 and 5 are correct outputs.

So when `<` means "sequenced before" and `~` means "indeterminately sequenced", we have:

`(value computations for print()'s arguments ~ execution of set()) < execution of print()`

Comment: [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5523366/607084) refers to a previous version of the C++ standard and states that the end of a function call is a sequence point. [Cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/eval_order) says "If a sequence point is present between the subexpressions E1 and E2, then both value computation and side effects of E1 are sequenced before every value computation and side effect of E2". Therefore I am not sure that there is any undefined behaviour (at least according to a previous standard).

Comment: @Xeno: Look again at the last paragraph in this answer.

Comment: This seems correct with your additional edited explanation. Perhaps the standard should include a "sequenced before" rule for chained methods similar to the comma operator to make this behaviour deterministic, though I suppose this could potentially introduce other defects.

Answer (score 2):

There's no guarantee in C++ about the order in which function arguments in a single expression are evaluated, not even when these functions are chained method calls. You are invoking undefined behavior here and that's what you get.

The . operator *does* imply sequencing, but only insofar that the expression before the . has to be fully evaluated before the member is accessed. It doesn't mean that the evaluations of subexpressions are suspended until that point.

Also, don't pass `int`s by `const int&`, there's no way this could be faster than passing an `int` directly (unless for some strange reason `int` doesn't fit into a processor word and the reference does).

Comment: I was under the impression that the dot operator "." is a sequence point, where everything before and after must be evaluated in order.

Comment: @Xeno Looking it up. If that's the case, I'm sorry and I'm gonna remove this answer.

Comment: @Xeno The way I read the standard, the only thing that's guaranteed is that the call to `set` is sequenced before the call to `print`, I haven't actually found anything that implies that the evaluation of all arguments to `print` must be sequenced after the call to `set`. If anyone could point us to the part of the standard that says that's the case, this would indeed be a bug in gcc.

Comment: [Cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/eval_order) states "If a sequence point is present between the subexpressions E1 and E2, then both value computation and side effects of E1 are sequenced before every value computation and side effect of E2". The side effect of i=10 from E1 should be sequenced before the value computation of i+5 in E2 then, should it not?

Comment: @Xeno It needs to occur before print is called, but not before `i+5` is evaluated.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I think I misinterpreted how the i+5 and print expressions were related.

Answer (score 0):

[too long for a comment:]

If adding

```
Test& add(int& i, const int toadd)
{
  i += toadd;
  return *this;
}
```

This call

```
t.set(i).add(i, 5).print(i);
```

returns

```
15
```

From this I conclude that the culprit is the  `i + 5` as parameter to print.