# Expression priority? How this result happens?

Tags: c++

In cpp, the result of the following code snippet is: 5 5 5
But in java, the result of the same code snippet is: 3 5 7
I do not know why, is there anyone could explain it?
Thanks a lot!

```
class H
{
  public:
    H &pr (int n, char * prompt)
    {
        cout<<prompt<<n<<" ";
        return *this;
    }

    H &fn(int n)
    {
        return pr(n,"");
    }
};

void test()
{
    int v=3;
    H h;
    h.fn(v).fn(v=5).fn((v=7));
}
```

Comment: The short answer is "C++ isn't Java."

Comment: BTW, I love questions that let me bust out some disassembly. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> In cpp, the result of the following code snippet is: 5 5 5 But in java, the result of the same code snippet is: 3 5 7 I do not know why,

Because C++ ain't Java :)

You are mutating the variable `v` in the last two function calls.  Let's look at the dissassembly (debug here to see things more clearly, in release a static value of `5` is used, but it could also be `7` just as easily.  You'll see why):

```
    h.fn(v).fn(v=5).fn((v=7));
00411565  mov         dword ptr [v],7 
0041156C  mov         dword ptr [v],5 
00411573  mov         eax,dword ptr [v] 
00411576  push        eax
```

The order of expression evaluation is not guaranteed to be the order that you call the functions here.  You are modifying `v` between [sequence points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point).  `7` gets assigned to `v`, then `5`, then the first function is called.  Note that it doesn't have to be `7` and then `5` in that order, it could be swapped!  The order of evaluation is unspecified, it could be anything.

You have a chain of functions which mutate `v` twice.  You cannot count on the fact that each mutation will occur in the order you typed it here.

We can simplify it.  Let's say we have two functions; `x` and `y` that both return an `int`.  If I write:

```
int k = x() + y();
```

There is no guarantee that `x()` will be called before `y()`.  So, if you are mutating an argument common to both functions then the mutation may occur in the call to `y()` first, which is what you are seeing.

Comment: +1 To make it a bit more explicit: The program has *Undefined Behavior* by the standard, and that means that the program can basically produce any of the following outputs: 3 5 6; 3 5 5; 3 7 7; 5 5 5; 5 5 7; 5 7 7; 7 7 7 (and possibly others that I skipped in between)

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that the standard does not guarantee how the expressions are evaluated.

Oh well, it does it partially but if you compile that code you get a specific warning that states

```
warning: operation on ‘v’ may be undefined
```

I think this question can enlighten you about this issues: [Is this code well-defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709727/is-this-code-well-defined)