# What made i = i++ + 1; legal in C++17?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17

Before you start yelling undefined behaviour, this is *explicitly* listed in [N4659 (C++17)](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/intro.execution#17)

```
  i = i++ + 1;        // the value of i is incremented
```

Yet in [N3337 (C++11)](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/intro.execution#15)

```
  i = i++ + 1;        // the behavior is undefined
```

What changed?

From what I can gather, from [[N4659 basic.exec]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/intro.execution#17)

> Except where noted, evaluations of operands of individual operators and of subexpressions of individual expressions are unsequenced. [...] The value computations of the operands of an operator are sequenced before the value computation of the result of the operator. If a side effect on a memory location is unsequenced relative to either another side effect on the same memory location or a value computation using the value of any object in the same memory location, and they are not potentially concurrent, the behavior is undefined.

Where *value* is defined at [[N4659 basic.type]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.types#4)

> For trivially copyable types, the value representation is a set of bits in the object representation that determines a *value*, which is one discrete element of an implementation-defined set of values

From [[N3337 basic.exec]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/intro.execution#15)

> Except where noted, evaluations of operands of individual operators and of subexpressions of individual expressions are unsequenced. [...] The value computations of the operands of an operator are sequenced before the value computation of the result of the operator. If a side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to either another side effect on the same scalar object or a value computation using the value of the same scalar object, the behavior is undefined.

Likewise, value is defined at [[N3337 basic.type]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/basic.types#4)

> For trivially copyable types, the value representation is a set of bits in the object representation that determines a *value*, which is one discrete element of an implementation-defined set of values.

They are identical except mention of concurrency which doesn't matter, and with the usage of *memory location* instead of *scalar object*, where

> Arithmetic types, enumeration types, pointer types, pointer to member types, `std::nullptr_t`, and cv-qualified versions of these types are collectively called scalar types.

Which doesn't affect the example.

From [[N4659 expr.ass]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.ass#1)

> The assignment operator (=) and the compound assignment operators all group right-to-left. All require a modifiable lvalue as their left operand and return an lvalue referring to the left operand. The result in all cases is a bit-field if the left operand is a bit-field. In all cases, the assignment is sequenced after the value computation of the right and left operands, and before the value computation of the assignment expression. The right operand is sequenced before the left operand.

From [[N3337 expr.ass]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/expr.ass#1)

> The assignment operator (=) and the compound assignment operators all group right-to-left. All require a modifiable lvalue as their left operand and return an lvalue referring to the left operand. The result in all cases is a bit-field if the left operand is a bit-field. In all cases, the assignment is sequenced after the value computation of the right and left operands, and before the value computation of the assignment expression.

The only difference being the last sentence being absent in N3337.

The last sentence however, shouldn't have any importance as the left operand `i` is neither *"another side effect"* nor *"using the value of the same scalar object"* as the *id-expression* is a lvalue.

Comment: You have identified the reason why: In C++17, the right operand is sequenced before the left operand. In C++11 there was no such sequencing. What, precisely, is your question?

Comment: @Robᵩ See last sentence.

Comment: There are two unsequenced side effects, both writes: `i =` has the side effect of writing to `i`. `i++` has the side effect of writing to `i`.

Comment: @Robᵩ If they're unsequenced, that'd make the example in the standard so utterly wrong that I'd be very hesitant to claim they're unsequenced.

Comment: They are unsequenced in C++11, sequenced in C++17. Hence the different examples.

Comment: Does anyone have a link to the motivation for this change? I would like a static analyser to be able to say "you don't want to do that" when faced with code like `i = i++ + 1;`.

Comment: @NeilButterworth, it's from the paper [p0145r3.pdf](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2016/p0145r3.pdf): "Refining Expression Evaluation Order for Idiomatic C++".

Comment: @xaizek Which bit of that, exactly - I couldn't see anything relevant, but maybe that's my bad.

Comment: @xaizek - On a cursory glance of that paper, section 5 implies that it *doesn't* cover the case of `++`.

Comment: @NeilButterworth, section number 2 says that this is counter intuitive and even experts fail to do the right thing in all cases. That's pretty much all their motivation.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth, the paper adds that wording about the assignment operator. It doesn't work on unary expressions in all contexts, but affect how they are processed as part of assignment as the accepted answer explains.

Comment: I'd say that any compiler that can't read that is buggy.

Comment: N4700 is a more current draft of C++17.

Comment: So, what happens when you go "c=c++ +1;"? Is it the same thing as "c=c+2"?

Comment: @nick012000 that would be c=c+1, since tha value produced by c++ + 1 is c+1.

Comment: @nick012000 The OP's first line of code mentions what that does. Although IMHO the comment should have said "gets 1 added to it" rather than "is incremented".

Comment: @Robᵩ Questions like these are why this proposal exists: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0431r0.htm but of course it wasn't championed properly at any committee meetings and probably just died a slow death.

Answer (score 150, accepted):

In C++11 the act of "assignment", i.e. the side-effect of modifying the LHS, is sequenced after the *value computation* of the right operand. Note that this is a relatively "weak" guarantee: it produces sequencing only with relation to *value computation* of the RHS. It says nothing about the *side-effects* that might be present in the RHS, since occurrence of side-effects is not part of *value computation*. The requirements of C++11 establish no relative sequencing between the act of assignment and any side-effects of the RHS. This is what creates the potential for UB.

The only hope in this case is any additional guarantees made by specific operators used in RHS. If the RHS used a prefix `++`, sequencing properties specific to the prefix form of `++` would have saved the day in this example. But postfix `++` is a different story: it does not make such guarantees. In C++11 the side-effects of `=` and postfix `++` end up unsequenced with relation to each other in this example. And that is UB.

In C++17 an extra sentence is added to the specification of assignment operator:

> The right operand is sequenced before the left operand.

In combination with the above it makes for a very strong guarantee. It sequences *everything* that happens in the RHS (including any side-effects) before *everything* that happens in the LHS. Since the actual assignment is sequenced *after* LHS (and RHS), that extra sequencing completely isolates the act of assignment from any side-effects present in RHS. This stronger sequencing is what eliminates the above UB.

(Updated to take into account @John Bollinger's comments.)

Comment: Is it really correct to include "the actual act of assignment" in the effects covered by "the left hand operand" in that excerpt?  The standard has separate language about the sequencing of the actual assignment.  I take the excerpt you've presented to be limited in scope to the sequencing of the left-hand and right-hand sub-expressions, which does not seem to be sufficient, in combination with the rest of that section, to support well-definedness of the OP's statement.

Comment: Correction: the actual assignment is still sequenced after the value computation of the left operand, and evaluation of the left operand is sequenced after (complete) evaluation of the right operand, so yes, that change is sufficient to support the well-definedness the OP asked about.  I'm just quibbling the details, then, but these do matter, as they might have different implications for different code.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: I would think guaranteeing the sequence of the left-side lvalue evaluation might needlessly impair the efficiency of every simple straightforward code generation.  Straightforward evaluation of `*foo() = globalVariable;`, for example, would invoke `foo()`, then fetch `globalVariable` and store it to the pointer received from `foo()`.  Capturing the value of `globalVariable` before the call if code doesn't need it would add cost; if code does need the variable before the call, copying it to a temporary variable shouldn't add any cost compared with the mandated semantics.

Comment: I don't disagree, @supercat, but the standard says what it says, and conforming programs must comply.  That's in an "as if" sense, however: a program has a great deal of internal leeway, provided that its external behavior is exactly *as if* it operated strictly as the standard specifies.  With regard to your particular example, the catch is of course whether the compiler can prove that `foo()` will not modify `globalVariable`.  Unless it can do so, it needs to make that temporary copy before performing the function call.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: I find it curious that the authors of the Standard would make a change that impairs the efficiency of even straightforward code generation and has historically not been necessary, and yet balk at defining other behaviors whose absence is a much bigger problem, and which would seldom pose any meaningful impediment to efficiency.

Comment: I'm right there with you, @supercat.  I guess the standard committee wanted to clear up this source of perpetual new-programmer surprise, but that's a pretty weak reason, and I'm not at all convinced that the benefit justifies the cost.  Moreover, other, similar undefinedness issues remain, such as with evaluating `i++ + i`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: What's particularly odd here is that this could in some cases represent a breaking change, since some implementations could legitimately have guaranteed behavior contrary to the new Standard.  I don't really mind cases like `i++ + i` (nor `i=i++` because a programmer who wants any particular ordering can easily demand one.  Much more problematic is the inability to block compiler reordering of unqualified object accesses across certain operations--telling the compiler that in a sequence like `foo(); barrier(); boz();`, the compiler may not reorder any operations...

Comment: ...from `foo` into `boz`, nor vice versa, even if those operations *seem* to operate on "ordinary" (unqualified) objects.  In many cases, it isn't practical to use qualifiers on objects accessed via outside code, which might be changed in ways the compiler doesn't know about *at times that code isn't running*.  Note that dealing with hardware memory reordering would be the programmer's responsibility, but a programmer can't deal with compiler reordering without tools to control it.

Comment: @supercat I find it curious that they sequenced it backwards, right to left!  Actually, not curious as much as idiotic.

Comment: @Kaz: For compound assignments, performing the left-side value evaluation after the right side allows something like `x -= y;` to be processed as `mov eax,[y] / sub [x],eax` rather than `mov eax,[x] / neg eax / add eax,[y] / mov [x],eax`.  I don't see anything idiodic about that.  If one had to specify an ordering, the most efficient ordering would probably be to perform all computations necessary to *identify* the left-side object first, then evaluate the right operand, then the *value* of the left object, but that would require having a term for the act of resolving the left object's id'ty.

Comment: @supercat Since `x -= y` doesn't contain any side effects other than updating the value of `x`, the ordering requirements are moot; it can be processed as the former machine sequence. Not to mention that it's well-defined going back to K&R C.

Comment: @Kaz: If `x` and `y` were `volatile`, that would have side-effects.  Further, the same considerations would apply to `x += f();`, where `f()` modifies `x`.

Answer (score 34):

You identified the new sentence

> The right operand is sequenced before the left operand.

and you correctly identified that the evaluation of the left operand as an lvalue is irrelevant. However, *sequenced before* is specified to be a transitive relation. The complete right operand (including the post-increment) is therefore *also* sequenced before the assignment. In C++11, only the *value computation* of the right operand was sequenced before the assignment.

Answer (score 10):

In older C++ standards and in C11, definition of the assignment operator text ends with the text:

> The evaluations of the operands are unsequenced.

Meaning that side-effects in the operands are unsequenced and therefore definitely undefined behavior if they use the same variable.

This text was simply removed in C++11, leaving it somewhat ambiguous. Is it UB or is it not? This has been clarified in C++17 where they added:

> The right operand is sequenced before the left operand.

---

As a side note, in even older standards, this was all made very clear, example from C99:

> The order of evaluation of the operands is unspecified. If an attempt is made to modify
>   the result of an assignment operator or to access it after the next sequence point, the
>   behavior is undefined.

Basically, in C11/C++11, they messed up when they removed this text.

Answer (score 3):

*This is further information to the other answers and I'm posting it as the code below is often asked about as well*.

The explanation in the other answers is correct and also applies to the following code which is now well-defined (and does not change the stored value of `i`):

```
i = i++;
```

The `+ 1` is a red herring and it's not really clear why the Standard used it in their examples, although I do recall people arguing on mailing lists prior to C++11 that maybe the `+ 1` made a difference due to forcing early lvalue conversion on the right-hand side. Certainly none of that applies in C++17 (and probably never applied in any version of C++).