# Is i = v[i++] legal in C++17?

Tags: c++, c++17, operator-precedence, sequence-points

I understand that the expression

```
i = v[i++]
```

causes undefined behavior pre-C++17, since we are not sure which action takes place first: the result of `i++` being put back to `i`, or the value of `v[i]` being assigned to `i`. But things seem to have changed in C++17.

From [N4659 expr.ass](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.ass#1)

> The assignment operator (=) and the compound assignment operators all
>   group right-to-left. All require a modifiable lvalue as their left
>   operand and return an lvalue referring to the left operand. The result
>   in all cases is a bit-field if the left operand is a bit-field. In all
>   cases, the assignment is sequenced after the value computation of the
>   right and left operands, and before the value computation of the
>   assignment expression. **The right operand is sequenced before the
>   left operand.**

It seems to me that in C++17, both value computation and side effect of v[i++] is sequenced **before** assignment operation(=), which makes `i = v[i++]` legal, with things taking place in the following order:

1. value of `v[i]` is retrieved
2. side effect of `i++` is enforced, `i` is incremented by 1
3. the value of `v[i]` retrieved in step 1 is assigned to `i`

Am I correct?

Comment: 1 and 2 can be swapped

Comment: [What made i = i++ + 1; legal in C++17?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47702220/4389800)

Comment: Legal or not, that code would fail a code review.

Comment: @Caleth But why? Suppose i = 1 at the beginning, if things took place as I said, v[1] is retrieved in step 1. If steps 1 and 2 were swapped, then v[2] will be retrieved in step 2. So swapping steps 1 & 2 obviously produces different results? I'm puzzled.

Comment: @john Yes, but I'm just using this code as an example to test if my understanding of the new standard is accurate.

Comment: @megamonium: 1 and 2 swapped, would *"result"* in `++i, v[i - 1]`;

Comment: In that example, `i++` results in the *value* `1`, and afterward `i == 2`. The `1` is used to index `v`, it no longer has a relation to `i`.

Comment: @john https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity :P

Comment: I see. So you are saying that `i` may be incremented before or after the pre-increment value of `i` is used to index into `v`. It is not specified by the standard. Got you.