# How the post-increment operator works exaclty. Are there some exceptions?

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior, post-increment

Consider this piece of code

```
int j = 0;
int x = 0;

for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
    j = x++;
    cout<<x<<" ";
}
```

Output:

`1 2 3 4 5`

Now consider this

```
int j=0;

for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
    
    j = j++;
    cout<<j<<" "; 
}
```

Output:

`0 0 0 0 0`

My doubt is why is `j` not being incremented after it is assigned the value `0`. Isn't `j=j++;` equivalent to `j = j;` `j++;` and if it isn't then what's going on with the first case. I know it's a silly doubt but I couldn't figure this out by myself.

Comment: `j++` evaluates to the previous value of `j`, zero on every occasion. By assigning it back to `j` you basically reset the latter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Isn't j=j++; equivalent to j = j; j++;

No absolutely not, and this is one of the most common misunderstandings about the pre and post increment operators.

The true equivalent of `j = j++;` is

```
int temp = j;
++j;
j = temp;
```

Beginners think that the post increment happens after everything else. But it's not true. The increment happens after the value is taken, not after the rest of the statement is executed. You can see that in the code above, the value of `j` is taken `temp = j;`, then the increment happens `++j;`, then the value is used `j = temp;`.

And as has been said several times, this code only has a defined meaning from C++17, before that it was undefined.

Answer (score 2):

> My doubt is why is j not being incremented after it is assigned the value 0. Isn't j=j++; equivalent to j = j; j++; and if it isn't then what's going on with the first case.

No, because `j = j++;` is undefined. See this and other examples in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior#Examples_in_C_and_C++

Comment: This is no longer undefined behavior in C++17: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47702220/what-made-i-i-1-legal-in-c17

Comment: @vll thanks, didn't know about that change in C++17

Answer (score 2):

```cpp
j = j++;
```

- First, the right-hand side expression evaluates i.e `j++`.
- As we know `j++` returns the previous value of j (i.e value before incrementing j). So, here `j++` returns `0`.
- Finally, this turns out to be `j = 0;`

The same thing happens every iteration and that's the reason only `0`'s are printed.

**Note:**

As others mentioned, this is defined behavior from ***C++17***

Answer (score 1):

It's a undefined behavior under c++11, and both clang++ and g++ complain about it.

```xml
test.cpp:7:10: warning: multiple unsequenced modifications to 'j' [-Wunsequenced]
    j = j++;
      ~  ^
1 warning generated.
```

But it's no longer ub in c++17.

Answer (score 0):

```
j = j++;
```

lead to undefined behavior，there is a concept named sequence point in C++, see:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point

Comment: AFAIK, the concept of sequence points no longer exists in C++ since C++ 11. Instead, operations are defined as being sequenced before or after other operations.

Comment: This is no longer undefined behavior in C++17: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47702220/what-made-i-i-1-legal-in-c17

Comment: @vll: Great point! You should post an answer.