# unsequenced modification and access to 'a' [-Wunsequenced] a^=b^=a^=b;

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

hi everyone this is my code below

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void printArray(int arr[],int size){
    cout<<"[ ";
    for(int i = 0;i<size;++i){
        cout<<arr[i]<<", ";
    }
    cout<<"\b\b ]\n";
}

void swap(int &a,int &b){
    a^=b^=a^=b;
}

void bubbleSort(int arr[],int n){
    for(int i = 0;i<n-1;++i){
        bool isSwap = false;
        for(int j = 0;j<n-1-i;++j){
            if(arr[j]>arr[j+1]){
                isSwap = true;
                swap(arr[j],arr[j+1]);
            }
        }
        if(!isSwap)
            break;
    }
}

int partition(int arr[],int l,int r){
    int i = l-1;
    int pivot = arr[r];
    for(int j = l;j<r;++j){
        if(arr[j]<pivot){
            ++i;
            swap(arr[j],arr[i]);
        }
    }
    swap(arr[r],arr[++i]);
    return i;
}

void quickSort(int arr[],int l,int r){
    if(l<r){
        int pivot_index = partition(arr,l,r);
        quickSort(arr,l,pivot_index-1);
        quickSort(arr,pivot_index+1,r);
    }
}


int main(){
    int a[] = {2,4,6,7,8,9,2,3,4,1,9,2,1,6,2,3,22};
    int size = sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);
    printArray(a,size);
    quickSort(a,0,size-1);
    printArray(a,size);
    return(0);
}
```

I was practicing  comparison based sorting algorithms  in the above code.
bubbleSort works fine but quickSort algorithm gives wrong result.

I usually compile my code using g++ compiler  but sometime I also use clang++
For better code warning and suggestion.

When I compiled above code with clang++ it gave this warning

```
1.cpp:14:9: warning: unsequenced modification and access to 'a' [-Wunsequenced]
        a^=b^=a^=b;
         ~~    ^
1 warning generated.
```

So there is a problem with the swap algorithm but my swap algorithm logic is correct.
I used the same swap in bubbleSort and this worked with this. algorithms(bubbleSort).

But it's not working with quickSort logic.

I just want to know why it's not working with quick sort.

Comment: Why do you think the warning (and thus the swap code) is the cause of quicksort not working?

Comment: you get exactly same warning by calling `bubbleSort` https://godbolt.org/z/99zv8z9rW

Comment: The behaviour you highlight is undefined before C++17; but, I believe, it is fully sequenced according the C++17 (and later) Standards.

Comment: why are you writing your own `swap` anyhow? Doing that in combination with `using namespace std;` is recipe for confusion and desaster.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47753609/10871073) explains assignment sequencing in C++11 and C++17. Presumably, it is also relevant for compound assignments.

Comment: The `a^=b^=a^=b` is unsequenced, so will result in **undefined behavior**.  `std::swap` already is available, and will do the swap correctly (and in this case, more efficiently).  But if you insist of using XOR, you'll want `a^=b; b^=a; a^=b;`

Comment: fwiw, no warning with c++17: https://godbolt.org/z/f4hWf14G6. You better change your attitiude "So there is a problem with the swap algorithm but my swap algorithm logic is correct." it cannot be correct and wrong at the same time. 99.99% of all casese the compiler is right

Comment: wrong code can produce right results. sometimes, when you are lucky (or unlucky). That doesnt make it less wrong

Comment: @Eljay Even with `void swap(int& a, int& b){a^=b; b^=a; a^=b;}`, the result is still wrong if `a` and `b` refer to the same variable, in which case it is equivalent to `a=b=0;`.

Comment: @prapin  void swap(int &a,int &b){
    if(a!=b)
        {a^=b^=a^=b;}
}

Comment: @prapin • Agreed, due to the non-aliasing assumption.  The result would be undefined behavior, which may be 0, but may be something else.