# PreIncrement/PostIncrement Operators Magic! Annoying me :-/

Tags: c++, syntax, expression, cout

```
        int a = 0;

        cout << a << a+1 << a << 1+a << a;
        // output is 01010 , ok fine i understand it! :-)

        cout << endl;

        cout << a << ++a << a << a++ << a;
        // output is 22202 ,
        // Plzzz help me how compiler interprets my this statement
        // i cant understand  :-(



            int x = 1;
            cout << ++x + ++x;
            // output is 6
            // how ??
```

Please if anyone could explain it to me how these outputs are coming :-)
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: The last one is  pretty easy. You have 1, autoincrement it two times (3), add it two times (3+3). Anyway, I would only use pre/postincremnt in the simplest situations, it is too risky.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the type of `x`. If `x` is a built-in type (e.g., `int`) then you have undefined behavior because you're modifying `x` twice without an intervening sequence point<sup>1</sup>.

If `x` is a user-defined type, then [you have unspecified behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2603355/179910).

---

<sub>1. Technically C++11 has change the terminology so "sequence point" is no longer used, bu the effect is the same.</sub>