# C++ pointer post increment strangeness

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, post-increment

In my cout statement:

```
cout << ia[cnt++] << "\t" << *beg << "\t" << beg++ << endl;
```

`beg++` affects the output of the earlier `*beg` statement, and I can't understand why?

Full code:

```
int ia[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
int *beg = begin(ia);   // pointer to the first element in ia
int *last = end(ia);    // pointer one past the last element in ia
int cnt = 0;

while (beg != last)
{
    cout << ia[cnt++] << "\t" << *beg << "\t" << beg++ << endl;
}
```

Moving the incrementation of `beg` to after the cout statement causes the code to function as I would expect. Can anyone please explain what's happening here?

Comment: According to the answers on [The result of int c=0; cout<<c++<<c;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2603312/the-result-of-int-c-0-coutcc), `operator<<` is not a sequence point.

Comment: Besides the unspecified order of evaluations of subexpressions (as explained in the duplicate), you also have undefined behaviour - unsequenced access and modification of `beg`. The code is illegal and practicaly anything can happen. See [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/why-are-these-constructs-using-undefined-behavior) for more information.

Comment: @remyabel this is also true.