# Order vs. Associativity

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [cout << order of call to functions it prints?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129230/cout-order-of-call-to-functions-it-prints)

What is the difference between order and associativity when evaluating a compound expression?

In the following example, I don't see the effect of order on the `result` of expression. The `result` is always `3` like the functions would have been called from left to right as arithmetic operators being left associative.

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int Func1(int &i)
{
    return i;
}

int Func2(int &i)
{
    return i++;
}

int main()
{
    for (int index = 0; index < 999999999; index++)
    {
        int i = 0;

        int result = (Func2(i) + Func1(i) + Func1(i) + Func2(i));

        cout << result << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Charles: I think, it's not a duplicate. the order in case of `cout` is well-defined!

Comment: @Nawaz: It's exactly the same issue. The associativity of `+` is well-defined too.

Comment: @Nawaz The order of evaluation isn’t well-defined in the case of `cout` either.

Comment: @Konrad: Yes. I recall that `operator<<` is free function. Anyway, voted to closed this!

Comment: Is there any way to know if the order of evaluation isn't well-defined in my case?

Comment: @cpx: Yes. See my answer and the quotation from the Standard itself.

Comment: I think I'll just have to go with it except that I don't see any change in `result` evaluated from my expression.

Answer (score 4):

```
 int result = (Func2(i) + Func1(i) + Func1(i) + Func2(i));
```

The order in which these functions are called is unspecified by the language!

The section $5/4 from the C++ Standard (2003) reads,

> Except where noted, **the order of
>   evaluation of operands** of individual
>   operators and subexpressions of
>   individual expressions, and the order
>   in which side effects take place, is
>   **unspecified**.

So the free advice is : avoid writing such code. They're non-portable!

Comment: What do you mean by "the result is predictable"?

Comment: @cpx: Seeing the function definitions, you can calculate the value!

Comment: But if they were called in different order, the result won't be the same.

Comment: @cpx: You were right. I didn't notice that argument is passed by reference!

Comment: Please note the value has been passed by reference to each function thus which function will change it first, is undefined.

Comment: @cpx: I've quoted a reference from the standard. I think, that is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The result is very likely to be the same if you run the code multiple times, using the same compiler with the same compile options. However, if you change the options or try another compiler, you can get a different result.

As you use only simple functions on ints, there is nothing much to be gained from calling the functions in a different order, so either left-to-right or right-to-left would be the obvious choice. And your test code can't tell the difference! :-)