# Memory Management : Returning a vector element and deleting(pop_back) it

Tags: c++, templates, memory-management

Here is a Template class I've made to catch up on templates

```
template <typename T>
class Myclass {
    std::vector<T> v;    
public:
Myclass(): v({0}){;}
Myclass(const Myclass& M)
{
    this->v={1,2}; //ignore this I'm gonna use int for testing 
}
~Myclass()
{
    std::cout<<"Destructor";
}
void setter(T i)
{
    v.push_back(i);
}
auto getter() -> decltype(T)
{
     return v.back();
}
};
```

I would like to have the getter function return the last element in `v` and `pop_back()`. Now I could store the `back()` value in a variable and just `pop_back()`. But I was hoping I could come up with smart pointers to do the same. Here's what I came up with

```
auto getter() -> decltype(v.back())
{
    std::unique_ptr<T> p1 (new T);
    *p1=v.back();
    v.pop_back();
    return *p1;
}
```

and my main is

```
Myclass<int> m1;
m1.setter(5);
Myclass<int> m2=m1;
std::cout<<m1.getter()<<m1.getter()<<std::endl;
std::cout<<m2.getter()<<m2.getter()<<m2.getter();
```

Yeah I want to do it with local smart pointers so that I can "be sure" of the objects destruction. 
Now My program compiles but runs endless.

Comment: The smart idea here is even worse.

Comment: Calling `getter` three times inside the same statement is probably not a good idea. The order of evaluation is unspecified, so you could get them in any of the 6 possible orders.

Comment: @FredOverflow: I am not sure that applies here. The multiple cout << would translate to cout.operator<<(..).operator<<(...).operator<<...

That chain seems like it would evaluate in left-to-right order as it has been written.

Comment: @EnricoGranata Oh, the **operators** are definitely executed from left to right, but the **operands** can be evaluated in any order. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129230/), for example.

Comment: @FredOverflow: you gotta love C++ so much.... ;)

Comment: @EnricoGranata It's more of a love-hate relationship, really...

Comment: @FredOverflow: I meant more to say "C++ always has a new reason to deserve love" than "you personally love C++ a lot" to be honest.. but yeah love-hate is a good way to describe it

Comment: Getter is supposed to pop the vector too. so I don't see how it being called 3 times could be a problem.

Comment: @user3145076 The problem is that in `std::cout << f() << g() << h()`, there is no way to predict in which order the functions `f()`, `g()` and `h()` are going to be called. Again, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129230/) for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for heap allocation, just use a good old local variable:

```
T getter()
{
    T temp = std::move(v.back());
    v.pop_back();
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: +1, No need for `-> decltype(T)` either (as the code above shows).

Comment: @6502 There is no copy construction, only move construction. Assuming `T` has a move constructor, of course ;)

Comment: The problem is that if T has no move constructor and the copy construction throws at `return` point you get an exception but the value has been already removed from the vector and is lost. This IIRC was one of the reasons for which there is no `pop` (removing and returning) in C++ ... it's simply impossible to write correctly.

Comment: @6502 You did well in C++ history class! That's exactly why.

Comment: @6505 Thanks I always tried some generic implementation of it and never got it 100% exception free.