# Shared dereferenced pointer value displays different results (when applying implicit copy constructor). Why?

Tags: c++, pointers, copy-constructor

The output of this piece of code is

```
21
```

I am unable to explain it to myself. My thinking (what I learned) is that an *implicit copy constructor* is called (triggered by the *assignment*) and all elements are copied bit by bit. However this does not apply to external elements, like the private variable `val`, which is a pointer. So `b` has a different pointer, **but** it is pointing to the same element.

So I expected the result to be

```
22
```

That is `.get()` is called twice by `a` and `b` and thus the dereferenced pointer value should be `1` (after the first `get()`) and then `2` (after the second `get()`). Finally the values are written to the console output.

### C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {
    int *val;
public:

    A() {
        val = new int;
        *val = 0;
    }

    int get() {
        return ++(*val);
    }
};

int main() {
    A a, b = a;
    cout << a.get() << b.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why would you get the same return value from the two `get`s? Calling it again won't magically change the value returned by the first call.

Comment: I thought the get()s are evaluated first ant then printed to the console output. I guess I am wrong with that, considering the answers. Still trying to read and digest.

Comment: So you _actually_ expected the result to be `12`, not `22`? That's because you made a false assumption about operand evaluation order.

Comment: Well, I mean that the whole output would be done at the end. I don't know why, but I believed the order to be like that: the first get() increases the value, then the second get() increases the value and the it is printed and would be 22. I understand now that I am completely wrong with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what the code actually does:

```
cout.operator<<( a.get() ).operator<<( b.get() );
```

or

```
operator<<( operator<<( cout, a.get() ), b.get() );
```

(I can't get the latter to compile due to overloading issues, but it does happen behind the scenes)

Which means that the code evaluates std::endl before b.get(), and b.get() before a.get(). So b.get() increases val's pointed value by 1 and then returns 1, and a.get() increases val's pointed value by 1 and returns 2. The operators are called in the expected order after the parameters are evaluated. I'd guess this is compiler dependent, but I ran your code and got the 21 as well.

In this case you are using an implicit copy constructor. What it does is copy the memory of your instance a to instance b. (As you said, byte by byte)

So b now owns its own pointer which holds the same value as a's pointer, that is to the same address. Since you increase the value on get(), the returned value would never be the same so you would never get 22 as a result.

Edit: You didn't actually use std::endl, it's my habit.

Answer (score 2):

When using cout, evaluation of `a.get()` and `b.get()` is done in no specific order. Thus, in your example `b.get()` is evaluated first (to 1), and then `a.get()` (to 2), and then "21" is printed on screen.

Comment: Can you provide a reference of your statement? This piece of code was in an assessment of the C++ institute. And if the order is undefined I wonder how can they know exactly the output?

Comment: @Elyasin see [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129230/cout-order-of-call-to-functions-it-prints) for example

Comment: @Elyasin: Who's "they"? If you mean the programmer, then "they" _can't_. That's why you should evaluate the function call in a variable first.

Comment: It is an online training from the C++ Institute and that piece of code was part of an online assessment. So "they" means the guys who developed the C++ course and the assessment.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is one of sequence points: `std::cout << a.get() << b.get();` has no strict defined evaluation order for `a.get()` and `b.get()`.

See [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points/4176333#4176333) for all the explanations.

Answer (score 1):

First the get function is called for object b and then it is call for the object a, hence giving a o/p of 2 1

```
(gdb) s
main () at so2.c++:20
20          cout << a.get() << b.get();
(gdb) p &a
$6 = (A *) **0x7fffffffd0f0**
(gdb) p &b
$7 = (A *) *0x7fffffffd0e0*
(gdb) s
A::get (this=*0x7fffffffd0e0*) at so2.c++:14
14              return ++(*val);
(gdb) p *val
$8 = 0
(gdb) n
15          }
(gdb) p *val
$9 = 1
(gdb) s
A::get (**this=0x7fffffffd0f0**) at so2.c++:14
14              return ++(*val);
(gdb) s
15          }
(gdb) p *val
$10 = 2
```

From the above debuggging session we can see the flow and behavior.