# Queue realisation C++

Tags: c++, indexing, queue

My realization of queue works in a strange way: when I enqueue new elements - all is right, but when I start to dequeue - it removes the last added element despite the fact that at this moment my head is 1 and tail is bigger. What are the pecularities of indexing in C++? Why does it behave like this?
Here is my full code:
https://hastebin.com/odibusacuk.cpp

```
class Queue{
public:
int head=1;
int tail=1;
int q[MAX];

int Queue::enqueue(int x){
    if (isFull()){
        return 0;}
    else {
        q[tail]=x;
       cout << tail << " here is a tail\n";
        if (tail==sizeof(q)){
            cout << tail << " this is tail\n" ;
            tail=1;}
        else {
            tail=tail+1;
            }
        return x;
        }
}
int Queue::dequeue(){
if(isEmpty()){
    cout << " the queue is empty\n";
    return 0;}
else {
    int x=q[head];
    if (head==sizeof(q)){
        head=1;}
    else {
        head=head++;
return x;}
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please include a [mcve].

Comment: You need to show us what you have done so that we could correct it.

Comment: my output is:
4 9 6 3 enqueued
1-head and tail-5
3 dequeued

Comment: *What should I change?* -- Bad ask here.  Debugging your own code is part of learning how to write programs.  What debugging have you done?

Comment: i printed head and tail indices and elements but i can't understand why it works in this way. I mean, when I print I see that q[1] = 4 q[2] =9 etc but when i remove - the last element with(as i suppose) the last(tail) index is  removed

Comment: I can not reproduced it: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6140f1fd138bc8b4

Comment: it's strange. it works different in codeblocks..

Comment: @SamOsterman -- `sizeof(q)` -- If you expected this to give you the number of elements in the array `q`, this does not give you the number of elements in the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are having is because when you do something like

```
cout << k.enqueue(4) << " " << k.enqueue(9)  << ' ' << k.enqueue(6) << " " << k.enqueue(3) << " enqueued\n ";
```

it is not specified in what order these functions will be called.
In your example, they are being called from right to left.
This means your queue is actually

```
{ 0, 3, 6, 9, 4 }
```

0 is there since your are skipping element 0 and going directly to element 1.
Your head is pointing to 1, thus you will dequeue 3.

You can read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129230/cout-order-of-call-to-functions-it-prints).