# std::cout with preincrement and postincrement

Tags: c++

I've recently started to learn c++ and while I was testing myself with possible interview questions, I've ran into that chunk of code:

```
#include <iostream>

void F(int& y, int& x) {
    std::cout << x++ << --y;
}

void main() {
    int a = 5;
    F(a, a);
    std::cout << a;
}
```

And the output is:

```
455
```

So I do know that preincrement is faster than postincrement, but why if we swap arguments like:

```
...
std::cout << --y << x++;
...
```

the output suddenly changes to

```
555
```

Comment: "preincrement is faster than postincrement," no, you can't conclude that. You can only conclude that the decrement executed before the increment

Comment: What version of C++ are you using?  This behavior has changed recently.

Comment: Dupe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129230/cout-order-of-call-to-functions-it-prints This could be added to the target list as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38501587

Comment: @NathanOliver I am using Visual Studio 2019 16.7.5 with default C++ standart (not sure which one is set by default in there).

Comment: By default, VS2019 defaults to C++14 mode.  If you switch it to C++17 mode, you'll get the "expected" behavior.

Comment: @NathanOliver hm, right, it does work as expected. Do you know what causes that unexpected behaviour in previous standarts?

Comment: See the duplicate, all is explained there.

Comment: @NathanOliver Currently reading it. Thanks!

Comment: @MooingDuck Can you edit the target list please? The current target is for C. While the answers may be relevant, there are better C++ targets that I listed in my comment.

Comment: @cigien I did not know that was an option! Fixed!

Comment: @MooingDuck Oh, yes, it's a very nice feature. If you have a gold tag badge, you can edit the target lists if they're wrong, or add additional targets as you feel appropriate :)